# PDFKit's PDFDocument init(url: URL) does not work with HTTPS

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

When I try to use `PDFDocument.init(url: )`, I noticed that it worked with `http` but not with `https` URLs. Does anyone know why?

```
import PDFKit

let httpURL = URL(string: "http://www.axmag.com/download/pdfurl-guide.pdf")!
let doc1 = PDFDocument(url: httpURL) //makes a PDFDocument

let httpsURL = URL(string: "https://www.gnu.org/s/libmicrohttpd/tutorial.pdf")!
let doc2 = PDFDocument(url: httpsURL) //nil
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first glance, this appears to be kind of a common problem in the Cocoa frameworks; many APIs take URLs, but in many cases, it's not clear what schemes they will accept. Some only take file URLs, some only take HTTP, some take HTTP, and HTTPS, and the documentation often doesn't say anything about which is going to be the case. It's often a good assumption that if the documentation doesn't say otherwise, the API probably only accepts `file:` URLs.

However, when you look a little deeper, it's not as much of a problem as it appears at first glance. In your case, you can work around the problem trivially by using Data's `try init(contentsOf:)`, which *does* support HTTPS, and then initializing your `PDFDocument` from that, but this isn't actually the best way to go about it. What I'd actually recommend doing instead would be to use an asynchronous API like `URLSession` to load the PDF data from the server. The reason I suggest this is that loading data from the network can take time, especially with PDF files which can sometimes be quite large, and if you just try to load the file synchronously on the main thread, you'll block it and make your app appear as if it is locked up. By loading the PDF data asynchronously, you can provide progress information for your user, along with a way to cancel the operation, and if something goes wrong, like the network going down in the middle of the download, you can handle that error in a sensible way. Once the data's all downloaded, you can then use the resulting Data object to initialize a `PDFDocument`.

So to answer your question, my guess as to why `PDFDocument` doesn't support HTTPS is because a synchronous initializer like this isn't the recommended way to load something over a network, and thus, putting a lot of work into designing it for that purpose was not a priority.

Here is a link to Apple's recommendation that your networking be asynchronous: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH12-SW3

Comment: I'm trying `init(contentsOf:)` but I'm getting an error that it can't load the PDF. How can I go about this?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi If you read the entire answer, you'll see that I'm not actually advocating for use of `init(contentsOf:)`. `URLSession` is a much better way to retrieve the data from a remote server.

Comment: I've actually tried that as well with no luck. Trying both `dataTask` and `downloadTask` with no luck.

Comment: `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, resp, err) in
            self.viewer.document = PDFDocument(data: data!)
        }.resume()`

Comment: @MalikBrahimi The data you get in the closure you send to `dataTask` is only partial. You should create an empty mutable data object, append each `data` to it as it comes in, and then use the full data at the end to create the `PDFDocument`.

Comment: Oh okay, but how exactly is that implemented?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi This is out of scope for a comment on this answer. I suggest posting a new question, with code samples clearly showing what you've tried, including the exact wording of any error messages you've received.

Answer (score 6):

```
@IBOutlet var pdfView: PDFView!

var pdfDOC: PDFDocument!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        downloadPDF()
    }

  func downloadPDF(){
        let urlString = "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_tutorial.pdf"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return}
        do{
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            pdfDOC = PDFDocument(data: data)
            pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
            pdfView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            pdfView.displaysAsBook = true
            pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
            pdfView.document = pdfDOC
            pdfView.autoScales = true
            pdfView.maxScaleFactor = 4.0
            pdfView.minScaleFactor = pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit
        }catch let err{
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: PDFView is not showing up in storyboard when trying to give classnameThanks